# UICollectionViewFlowLayout with sections (but no section breaks)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionViewFlowLayout currently very simply:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(75, 75);
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2;
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2;
_collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;
```

I have multiple sections (cells from different sources), however, I would like to render the grid in a continuous fashion. So that there would be no visible breaks between the sections.

See the screenshot where for dev purposes I am rendering the same cells in two sections.

Any ideas, how I can get flow-layout to allow multiple sections but not have a break drawn?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Starting from a blank project, with a vanilla collection view and a layout object created like yours above, I don't get any spaces between sections at all. Are you implementing any other delegate methods such as those from the flow layout delegate protocol?

Comment: I would make a class that combines all the source into one. Some source of an iterator class since you do not need sections.

Comment: Can you post the code (how many arrays, etc) you are using for the source data?

Comment: Hi Damien, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @MarkGibson Nope! I ended up with a different UI design, so it wasn't required by me in the end. I don't think its possible with the flow layout.

Comment: Hey, Did you succeed to do that ? if yes how exactly you did that ? did you subclassing the flowlayouts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView remove section breaks with UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879230/uicollectionview-remove-section-breaks-with-uicollectionviewflowlayout)

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` does not provide a way to skip the line break when a new section begins. You need to write a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass that computes the layout attributes differently – alternatively have a look at [RDHCollectionViewGridLayout](https://github.com/rhodgkins/RDHCollectionViewGridLayout), which provides exactly that.

Answer (score -3):

With this method :

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
```

You should be able to do what you want.